# Jupyter Notebook Tensorflow MNIST import Error: ImportError: cannot import name batching

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I tried to execute this line in my application in Jupyter notebook.

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import read_data_sets
```

I get the following error:

```
.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py in <module>()
     23 
     24 # Add projects here, they will show up under tf.contrib.
---> 25 from tensorflow.contrib import batching
     26 from tensorflow.contrib import bayesflow
     27 from tensorflow.contrib import cloud

ImportError: cannot import name batching
```

I do not get this error if I ran it like this:

```
 python -c "from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data"
```

Can someone tell me what's causing the error in Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into similar issue with importing libraries from jupyter notebook, and the problem has always been that I forgot to install `jupyter` in my new conda environment, but jupyter is installed in the root environment.

Based on the error given, make sure you have jupyter installed within the `py27` conda environment. If it not installed, it will default to open the one in the root environment.

So in the terminal:

```
source activate py27  # activate py27 if on windows
conda install jupyter
```